# PL/SQL: Insert or Update Trigger "select count" results

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

My trigger takes an input. (NEW:input_id) With this input, it will generate new ID's using a dynamically generate queries. The instructions
for the dynamically generated queries are stored in QUERY_REF.
It uses a cursor to retrieve query_ids for generating dynamic queries:

```
CURSOR C_QUERY IS 
  SELECT QUERY_ID
    FROM QUERY_REF
    WHERE GENERATE_IND='Y';

OPEN C_QUERY;

LOOP
  FETCH C_QUERY INTO QUERY_ID_RET;
  EXIT WHEN C_QUERY%NOTFOUND;
```

INPUT_ID and QUERY_ID_RET have been used succesfully to create Output_ID in function gethostID.

I'm trying to run an insert, update based on whether a record is found. The Select counts are returning 0.
I discovered why the select counts were returning 0--I referenced the wrong table.  I still don't know why this is retrieving old dat.  Here is the entire trigger:

```
create or replace
TRIGGER INPUT_AUTO_QUERY_TRIG
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE
ON INPUT_TABLE
FOR EACH ROW
 DECLARE
   ACTION_VALUE       VARCHAR2(6);
   HOLD_EVENT_ID      VARCHAR2(256);
   HOLD_USER_ID      VARCHAR2(30);
   HOLD_PK_VALUE      INTEGER(10);
   HOLD_AUDIT_ITEM_ID INTEGER(10);
   QUERY_ID_RET       NUMBER;
   resultcount        NUMBER;
   HostID      VARCHAR2(256);
   QUERY_ID       NUMBER;
   INPUT_ID         NUMBER(38,0);
   GENERATE_IND       VARCHAR2(1);
   pragma autonomous_transaction;
CURSOR C_QUERY IS 
  SELECT QUERY_ID
    FROM QUERY_REF
    WHERE GENERATE_IND='Y';
BEGIN

OPEN C_QUERY;

LOOP
  FETCH C_QUERY INTO QUERY_ID_RET;
  EXIT WHEN C_QUERY%NOTFOUND;

 SELECT AUDIT_ID, USER_ID
   INTO HOLD_EVENT_ID, HOLD_USER_ID
   FROM AUDIT_EVENT_TEMP
   WHERE SESSION_ID = SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'SESSIONID');

   OutputID:=getHostID(:NEW.INPUT_ID,QUERY_ID_RET);

  IF INSERTING THEN
    INSERT INTO DETAIL
  (
  DETAIL_ID,
  INPUT_ID,
  OUTPUT_ID,
  QUERY_ID,
  ACTIVE_IND,
  CREATED_BY,
  DATE_CREATED,
  MODIFIED_BY,
  DATE_MODIFIED
  ) VALUES
  (
    DETAIL_SEQ.NEXTVAL,
    :NEW.INPUT_ID,
    OutputID,
    QUERY_ID_RET,
    'Y',
    HOLD_USER_ID,
    SYSDATE,
    HOLD_USER_ID,
    SYSDATE
  );

ELSIF UPDATING THEN

SELECT COUNT(QUERY_ID) INTO resultcount FROM DETAIL WHERE             INPUT_ID=:NEW.INPUT_ID AND QUERY_ID=QUERY_ID_RET;
    IF resultcount>0 THEN
    UPDATE PATIENT_DATA_SOURCE
    SET
  HOST_ID = HostID,
  ACTIVE_IND ='Y',
  MODIFIED_BY =HOLD_USER_ID,
  DATE_MODIFIED =SYSDATE
  WHERE INPUT_ID=:NEW.INPUT_ID
  AND QUERY_ID=QUERY_ID_RET;

--don't want to change: DETAIL_ID,QUERY_ID,INPUT_ID,CREATED_BY,          DATE_CREATED in update

  ELSE
      INSERT INTO DETAIL
  (
  DETAIL_ID,
  INPUT_ID,
  HOST_ID,
  QUERY_ID,
  ACTIVE_IND,
  CREATED_BY,
  DATE_CREATED,
  MODIFIED_BY,
  DATE_MODIFIED
  ) VALUES
  (
  DETAIL_SEQ.NEXTVAL,
  :NEW.INPUT_ID,
  HostID,
   QUERY_ID_RET,
  'Y',
    HOLD_USER_ID,
    SYSDATE,
    HOLD_USER_ID,
    SYSDATE
  );
END IF;
--end if insert or update inside update

END IF;
--end IF UPDATING
END LOOP;
Close C_QUERY;

COMMIT;
END INPUT_AUTO_QUERY_TRIG;
--end trigger
```

Comment: You've got two `IF INSERTING...` lines at the beginning.  I don't know if this was intentional, but as posted it appears that the `ELSIF UPDATING...` would never be reached as it's inside the outer `IF INSERTING...`.

Comment: Thank you, that was a copying mistake.

Comment: Can you post the full trigger?

Comment: I posted the full trigger.  I corrected the select count mistake, but I can't figure out why this is retrieving old data from table "INPUT" if this is an "after" trigger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no restrictions on using SELECT COUNT(*)
in a trigger - unless it is on the table the
trigger is defined on (possibility of a mutating
table).

http://psoug.org/reference/table_trigger.html

Does
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM query_str_ref 
      WHERE INPUT_ID=:NEW.INPUT_ID
        AND QUERY_ID=QUERY_ID_RET;

work on its own in an SQLPLUS session and return a 
count more than zero?

If this line returns the correct count outside
the trigger, then either something in the trigger could
be impacting the count before the line is reached or
the line might not be reached at all.

If this line DOESN'T return the correct count
outside the trigger then it might be a good idea
to check the QUERY_STR_REF table data,
the new value input  ID and the

Also, are you sure that the CURSOR /FETCH
on QUERY_REF to set QUERY_ID_RET is either inside
the trigger or accessible from the trigger,
and there is no interference (QUERY_REF is
not being altered by the triggering statement)?

Comment: Thank you so much. I was worried select count does not work inside a trigger.

Comment: Just a note; the time taken up by SELECT COUNT(*) can grow very easily depending on the indexing in the table etc.  This could really slow down the inserts on the table you're triggering on.

Comment: I found out I can't execute the dynamic query inside the function--it uses old data. I'm using the function to create the dynamic query, and run the query in the trigger.  I'm getting this error: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected.

Comment: ORA-00923 is a syntax error; it sounds like it is being generated in the function rather than in the trigger ; do you have the source for the function?

Comment: `create or replace
FUNCTION getHostQuery(
INPUT_ID NUMBER,
QUERY_ID NUMBER
)
RETURN VARCHAR2
AS
 query_str VARCHAR2(512);
 HOST_ID VARCHAR2(256);
 query_clause VARCHAR2(256);
 
BEGIN
 SELECT CONSTRUCTOR INTO query_clause from QUERY_ref where QUERY_ID=IN_QUERY_ID;
 query_str:= 'SELECT ' ||  query_clause || ' INTO  HostID FROM INPUT WHERE INPUT_ID=NEW:INPUT_ID';

 RETURN query_str;
END getHostQuery;
When I test that in command line, I get this:
SELECT NEW:FIRST_NAME||NEW:LAST_NAME||to_char(NEW:BIRTH_DATE,''yyyy/mm/dd'')     INTO  HostID FROM INPUT WHERE INPUT_ID=NEW:INPUT_ID`

Comment: In the result of the function, is SELECT NEW:FIRST_NAME||NEW:LAST_NAME||to_char(NEW:BIRTH_DATE,''yyyy/mm/dd'') supposed to be referencing :NEW.FIRST_NAME    Your syntax could be valid but if this is referring to a field in a trigger I have always seen it as :NEW.FIELD_NAME

Comment: I'm getting these errors: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
ORA-06512, line 37.  That is in the select hold_user_id clause.  That looks properly formed.  I'm trying to find the source of that error.

Comment: Are you sure AUDIT_EVENT_TEMP has the columns AUDIT_ID, USER_ID and SESSION_ID and the type of the variables HOLD_EVENT_ID, HOLD_USER_ID match the column definitions for AUDIT_ID, USER_ID in AUDIT_EVENT_TEMP?  Otherwise this looks valid; I tried the SYS_CONTEXT and that works: SELECT AUDIT_ID, USER_ID  INTO HOLD_EVENT_ID, HOLD_USER_ID FROM AUDIT_EVENT_TEMP WHERE SESSION_ID = SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'SESSIONID');

Comment: Thank you, it was an error with the sql clause.  I have since refactored the code so that the function returns a query string, and I run that in an "execute immediate" statement.  Now I'm cleaning up a binding variable problem (I'm looking up dynamic query execution in an AFTER trigger)